# Synchronous loop with async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

This is what I need to accomplish:

I have a function (we will call it `thePromise`) that returns a promise.

I have an array containing different arguments to run `thePromise`.
Example:

```
var thePromise = function(options) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     // Some asynchronous code
     resolve(value);
   });
}

var parameters = [
  { a: 10, b: 15 },
  { a: 20, b: 30 }
];
```

I will sum the resolved `value` to a variable, let's call it `total`.

Here is where I'm stuck:
I need to run the promise with the next set of arguments only if the result of the promise summed to `total` is below a defined amount.

I tried to use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst)`.each()`, but this doesn't work becouse the next promise is called before I call the `next()` function.

Current (not working) solution:

```
async.each(paramaters, function(options, next) {
   thePromise(options).then(function(value) {
      total += value;

      if (total > 10) {
        return next('limited');
      }
      next();
   }).catch(next);
}, function(err) {
  if (err && err !== 'limited) { // Handle error }

  // Handle success
});
```

Comment: Try adding the function call that you use to iterate the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries), from the docs:

> The same as [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), only iterator is applied to each item in arr in series. The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed. This means the iterator functions will complete in order.

This way you can acheive a synchronous iteration of async calls

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. I had the solution already at hands. Thanks.